# ansible.windows.win_package pass inventory machine details to msi arguments

Tags: configuration, ansible, azure-devops

I'm trying to install MSI file with the help of `ansible.windows.win_package` module 
One of the arguments needs to hold the appserver machine name 
Trying the following syntax - didn't work (I shrink the arguments list in the following task file example):

```yaml
- name: Install Server.msi center_primary_dbserver
  ansible.windows.win_package:
    path: c:\r10_files\Server.msi
    arguments:
      ...
      AUTH=WINDOWS
      APPSERVER={{ center_primary_appservers }}
      RABBITSERVER={{ center_qservers.hosts[0] }}
      ... 
      THUMBPRINT={{ cert_thumbprint }}
      SECURED=1
      SQLSERVERNAME={{ inventory_hostname_short }}
      LOG_SIZE=100
      ...
  when: "'center_primary_dbservers' in group_names"
```

Here, is part of my inventory file:

```yaml
---
all:
  children:
    root:
      children:
        center:
          children:
            center_primary_appservers:
              hosts:
                vm1.domain.com:
            center_qservers:
              hosts:
                vm2.domain.com:
            center_primary_dbservers:
              hosts:
                vm3.domain.com:
```

As we can see - 
I need to place the value of the `center_primary_appserver` machine in `APPSERVER` argument,
and the value of the `center_qserver` machine in `RABBITSERVER` argument
For the `THUMBPRINT` I created a separate task file that it's results are registered with a `cert_thumbprint` variable, like this:

```yaml
- name: Import certificate thumbprint
  ansible.windows.win_certificate_store:
    path: "{{ cert_path.files[0].path }}"
    file_type: pkcs12
    password: "FooF!ght3rs"
    store_location: LocalMachine
    key_storage: machine
    state: present
  become: yes
  become_method: runas
  become_user: SYSTEM
  register: cert_thumbprint
  when: "'certificate_autohrities' in group_names"
```

So, currently, executing this task produces the following error:

```
{
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "arguments":
            ... 
            THUMBPRINT={'changed': False, 'skipped': True, 
                        'skip_reason': 'Conditional result was False'} 
            RABBIT_PARENT_SERVER=center_qservers.hosts[0] 
            SECURED=1
            SQLSERVERNAME=vm3
            LOG_SIZE=100 
            ...         
           }
        }
    }
}
```

To sum up the question:
What is the right syntax to:

- assign in MSI Arguments - registered variable from another task file (in our example: `cert_thumbprint`)?
- assign in MSI Arguments - machine varaible from inventory (in our example: `center_primary_appservers`, `center_qservers.hosts[0]`)?

Comment: Are you thinking that there only ever going to be one host in the "group" center_primary_appservers?  If so - are you sure you need it to be a group?

Comment: @Semicolon, In this particular lab - only one, In another lab - no. Flexibility is the key here